# Android Studio : Error: no main manifest attribute, in C:...\libs\opencsv-4.1.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error

I added the library to the project, but I get an error:

no main manifest attribute, in

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Android\MyClassesAndLessons\app\libs\opencsv-4.1.jar
```

What did I do wrong? How to fix?

Comment: Please include additional details on how your project is configured.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the jar file and add the library as a dependency in your app module `build.gradle` file as:

```
compile 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.1'
```

This could solve your problem.

Comment: now i am getting "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1255 -jar C:\Users\User\Desktop\Android\MyClassesAndLessons\app\libs\opencsv-4.1.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Users\User\Desktop\Android\MyClassesAndLessons\app\libs\opencsv-4.1.jar

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot for the dependencies section in the build.gradle file?

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XkqFXnE2otDh3Qz-73ai4O3RmUi5TeSd).

Comment: Your build.gradle file is ok.  Try clean and rebuild project. If it doesn't resolve the problem, do Invalidate caches and restart from the File menu.